# How to register XmlAdapter when using episodes with maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have 3 XSDs:
commonClasses, and 2 others which import this ones.

Now I use maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate my classes from these.
To prevent my Enums classes from being generated twice I added:

```
<extension>true</extension>
              <bindingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc1/generic/META-INF</bindingDirectory>
              <bindingIncludes>
                <include>generic.episode</include>
              </bindingIncludes>
```

To the execution steps for the other two XSDs.

Now this correctly prevents the files from being generated twice.

However in the commonClasses there's an enum. Since by default these are converted by default to null, I need to make a custom XMLAdapter.
However I'm having issues with registring the adapter, since I can't have both an episode file and an XJB file according to: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/issues/131

I tried adding to the following to my XSD but that seems to be no dice either.

```
<xs:simpleType name="foo">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <xjc:javaType name="something.Foo"
                      adapter="something.FooAdapter" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
```

Is there anyone who could give me some pointers where I'm messing up?